# Python - Counting number of distinct pixels in an image

Tags: python, image

I am working on a Python script that counts the number of unique pixels in an image, then clusters similar pixels such as (100, 100, **101**) and (100, 100, 100) into a single pixel say (100, 100, 100). My script seems to work pretty fine. I take in a image of 50 by 50 pixels (2500 total) and run the script on it with around 17000 unique pixels and the script narrows it down to around 750 pixels and writes the output file.  They seem correct. However, when I use that output file again as input. I am getting that the number of unique pixels is actually higher than the input (around 1800). How is that so? Does the `Image.fromarray()` method end up modifying the numpy array I pass as a parameter?

```
import numpy
from numpy import linalg as LA
from PIL import Image

pixel_mapping = {}

def array_in_twod(one, two):
    for i in range(len(two)):
        if (numpy.array_equal(one, two[i])): #print 'found duplicate'
            return True
    return False

def close_enough(pixel, pixels, threshold): #for i in range(len(pixels)): #if (man_norm(pixel, pixels[i]) < threshold): #return pixels[i]#
    for i in range(len(pixels)):
        if(man_norm(pixels[i], pixel) < threshold):
            return pixels[i]
    return pixel

def man_norm(v1, v2):
    #print 'V1: ', v1, ' V2: ', v2
    if v1.shape[0] != v2.shape[0]: #Raise new ValueError('Lengths are not the same')
        print 'do nothing'
    else:
        length = v1.shape[0]
        diff = 0
        for i in range(length):
            #prevent overflow by subtracting larger number from smaller in
            #unsigned 8 bit integer
            if v1[i] > v2[i]:
                diff += v1[i] - v2[i]
            else:
                diff += v2[i] - v1[i]
    return diff
def compress_array(array):
    length = array.shape[0]
    width = array.shape[1]
    numPixels = array.shape[2]
    pixelMash = []
    for i in range(length):
        for j in range(width):
            arr = array[i][j]
            pixelMash.append(arr)
    return pixelMash
def distinct_pixels(array):
    no_dup = []
    for i in range(len(array)):
        curr_arr = array[i]# print curr_arr
        if array_in_twod(curr_arr, no_dup) == False:
            no_dup.append(curr_arr)
    #print 'Final result: ', len(no_dup)
    return no_dup

def totuple(a):
    try:
        return tuple(totuple(i) for i in a)
    except TypeError:
        return a

def cluster_pixels(array, threshold):
    clustered = []
    for i in range(len(array)):
        curr_pixel = array[i]
        output_pixel = close_enough(curr_pixel, array, threshold)
        if numpy.array_equal(curr_pixel, output_pixel):
            clustered.append(curr_pixel) #found no close enough matches
            curr_pixel = totuple(curr_pixel)
            if pixel_mapping.get(totuple(curr_pixel)) == None:
                pixel_mapping[curr_pixel] = curr_pixel
        else:
            if pixel_mapping.get(totuple(curr_pixel)) == None:
                curr_pixel = totuple(curr_pixel)
                pixel_mapping[curr_pixel] = output_pixel
            clustered.append(output_pixel)
    return numpy.array(clustered)



def tabulate_final_image(raw_picture):
    length = raw_picture.shape[0]
    width = raw_picture.shape[1]
    numElem = raw_picture.shape[2]

    result_picture = numpy.zeros((length, width, numElem))

    for i in range(length):
        for j in range(width):
            curr_pixel = raw_picture[i][j]
            mapped_pixel = pixel_mapping[totuple(curr_pixel)]
            result_picture[i][j] = numpy.array(mapped_pixel).astype('uint8')
    #print result_picture
    return result_picture


def fun():
    raw_picture = numpy.asarray(Image.open('poster_normaliza_jj.jpg'))
    unfiltered_pixels = compress_array(raw_picture)
    #print len(unfiltered_pixels)
    distinct_pixels = distinct_pixels(unfiltered_pixels)
    #print len(distinct_pixels)
    clustered_pixels = cluster_pixels(distinct_pixels, 7)
    #print len(cluster_pixels)
    no_duplicate_final =  distinct_pixels(clustered_pixels)
    print no_duplicate_final

'''
test out helper functions
print man_norm(numpy.array([1, 2, 1]), numpy.array([2, 2, 4]))

bank = numpy.array([[1, 2, 2], [1, 2, 5], [1, 4, 6]])
src = numpy.array([1, 6, 2])

print close_enough(src, bank, 5)
'''

fileName = 'out_out_out_out_out_out_poster_jj.jpg'

raw_picture = numpy.asarray(Image.open(fileName))
unfiltered_pixels = compress_array(raw_picture)
distinct_pixels_result = distinct_pixels(unfiltered_pixels)

print 'Number of Distinct Pixels Before', len(distinct_pixels_result)

clustered_pixels = cluster_pixels(distinct_pixels_result, 100)
no_duplicate_final =  distinct_pixels(clustered_pixels)
out_picture = tabulate_final_image(raw_picture)

#print raw_picture.shape

unfiltered_pixels = compress_array(out_picture)
distinct_pixels_result = distinct_pixels(unfiltered_pixels)
print 'Number of Distinct Pixels After', len(distinct_pixels_result)

svimg=Image.fromarray(out_picture.astype('uint8'))
svimg.save('out_' + fileName)

#print no_duplicate_final
```

Comment: Can you pastebin your intermediate file and link it?

Comment: http://imgur.com/FsUYP9u. This is the image I used. You can run compile this with the script/image in the same directory and it will generate an output image with the 'out' appended to the image name. Then, if you run the script again with `fileName` equal to the output image, then thats when the distinct number of colors changes unexpectedly.